# How to calculate the angle of the incline plane given no radial net force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

A bicycle and its rider have a total mass of $100kg$ and travel around a circular banked track at a radius of $20m$ and at a constant speed to $10ms^{-1}$, as shown. The track is banked so that there is no sideways friction force applied by the track on the wheels.

[image]

Part a) wants me to draw the net resultant force, which I already did:

[image]

b)Calculate the correct angle of bank for there to be no sideways friction force applied by the track on the wheels.

does no friction force means that friction force  = centripetal force? In which direction does the frictional force act? I fail to see how to include the angle into all this?

Based on the diagram that I have drawn, could it be $\tan \left(\theta \right)=\frac{opposite}{adjacent}=\frac{mg}{\frac{mv^2}{r}}$ But still couldn't get the right answer.

[image]

Comment: what do you think the horizontal component of the normal reaction force does?

Comment: Does my change in title help clarify what's intended? There's certainly friction, but the idea, I think, is to remove a vector component of force.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Why do you think there is friction ? The problem explicitly says there is no sideways frictional force. The only forces acting on the bicycle are the normal force from the track and its weight.

Comment: @gandalf61  The problem is sloppily stated.  If the banking is at the desired angle, there is no "sideways" force, and thus no sideways frictional force.  The friction can still be there, but resultant force only happens when there's motion in a particular direction.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I see what you mean - there are two alternative ways to read the question. Solution is the same in either case.

Answer (score 2):

The only forces acting on the bicycle are the normal force from the track, $N$, and the bicycle's weight $mg$. There is no friction and no need for friction. The net force $F_{net}$ must act horizontally, otherwise the bicycle would move up or down the bank. So $F_{net}$ is shown correctly in your diagram.

The net vertical force on the bicycle is zero, so $N \cos \theta = mg$. The net horizontal force is

$\displaystyle F_{net} = N \sin \theta = mg \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = mg \tan \theta$

But we also know that $F_{net}$ must be the centripetal force required to keep the bicycle moving in a circle, so

$\displaystyle F_{net} = \frac {mv^2}{r}$

From this you can see that your expression for $\tan \theta$ is upside down. (This is also clear since we expect $\theta$ to approach zero when $v$ approaches zero).

Comment: Thank you gandalf

Comment: Gandalf I got a question, why isn't $Fn = mgcos(\theta)$?

Comment: can you look at the diagram I dreew?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk The component of the bike’s weight along the plane of the track is indeed $mg\cos \theta$ but there is no need for a frictional force to balance this because the bike is not in equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

> does no friction force means that friction force = centripetal force? In which direction does the frictional force act? I fail to see how to include the angle into all this?

No !!!.

By saying no sideways friction force, the question is referring to the scenario in which the cyclist or the cycle **does not slip along the banked surface**.

So as you have drawn in the fbd , it experiences only normal force and it's weight .  Since weight is acting downward and perpendicular to the plane of the circular path it will have no component along the center of that circular path. So you are left only with the normal force and you can notice that normal force does have some components towards the center. So you can simply equate this component of normal force with the centripetal equation (i.e. $N_{component} = \frac{mv^2}{r}$).

Now it's all upon you .

Hope it helps.